# Hashed provinces on the trade good map mode

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

In the trade-good map mode, when I select a province, sometimes neighbouring provinces are hashed in the colour of that particular trade good. What does this represent?

[image: The trade good map mode]

[image: Some provinces are hashed]

[image: Even more hashed provinces]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer from the path notes 1.14:

- Improved the Trade Goods mapmode: possible trade goods are now shown as stripes on the map

I belive it was supposed to show stripes on only uncolonized provinces. I hope they're going to fix it soon.